# Android ,No backup to the extern sd card (/storage/sdcard1/)

Tags: android

I m trying to save a file in sd card at the following path.

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + dir + filename`

if sd card state is mounted.

```
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
```

One of my user complained

```
    No backup to the extern sd card (/storage/sdcard1/)
```

This issue raied in Galaxy Tab2 10.1.
I am little confused,i have nexus 4,where it has only internal memory.
and verified the same in S4,s3 and note 3 all worked fine.
Hope i am saving the file in right path and works fine in all devices.

how do i resolve complain ? any things is wrong ?

.

Comment: Have you made sure that the external storage is ready before using it?

Comment: yes..if its mounted then only i ll save the file sd card

Comment: The SD card might not be ready for storage, if say the user has connected it to his computer via a USB cable, or if he has explicitly locked it by use of an app.

Comment: is the SD card formatted properly ?

Answer (score 0):

The SD card might not be ready yet. Consider waiting for external storage to get ready, before writing to it, as shown below.

```
// Wait till external storage is initialized upon startup. 
private void awaitExternalStorageInitialization() {
    boolean mExternalStorageAvailable = false;
    boolean mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
    int count = 0;

    do {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if(count > 0) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Logger.log(e.getMessage(), Logger.LogType.ERROR, e);
            }
        }

        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            // We can read and write the media
            mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = true;
        } else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
            // We can only read the media
            mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
            mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
        } else {
            // Something else is wrong. It may be one of many other states,
            // but all we need to know is we can neither read nor write
            mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
        }
        count++;
    } while ((!mExternalStorageAvailable) && (!mExternalStorageWriteable) 
            && (count < 15));

    if(!mExternalStorageWriteable)
        Logger.log("External storage not ready yet", Logger.LogType.ERROR, null);
}
```

Comment: i  have a check for the sdcard, i am displaying message to the user in  all other failure cases